# Print out questions in sequential order in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, while-loop, zip, sequence

**Problem:**

I have a zip file that contains 13 xml files. Each file, except for the first one, contain a quiz question and several answers. When I upload the file to the below script it prints out the questions and the answers correctly, but NOT in order. The order of questions randomly shift each time I upload the zip-file.

**Question:**

Is there a way I can utilize the file names to tell the script to print out the questions in sequential order every time?

**Zip-file contain:**

- imsmanifest.xml
- item101008.xml
- item101009.xml
- item101010.xml
- item101011.xml
- item101012.xml
- item101013.xml
- item101014.xml
- item101015.xml
- item101016.xml
- item101017.xml
- item101018.xml
- item101019.xml

**PHP-script (warning, long script):**

```
<?php
    //Initialize counter
    $i = 0;

    //Go through each file
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) 
    {
        //Skipt the first loop
        if ($i > 1)
        {
            //Ignore misc file      
            if ($file != 'imsmanifest.xml')
            {
                //Create new DOM document
                $dom= new DOMDocument();

                //Load XML file
                $dom->load('uploads/' . $file);

                //Do not preserve white space
                $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

                //Check if correct answers should be displayed
                if (isset($_POST['XMLAnswers']))
                {
                    //Get correct answer
                    $correct = $dom->getElementsByTagName( "correctResponse" )->item(0)->nodeValue;

                    //Get question
                    $questions = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue;

                    //Print out question
                    echo '<h4>' . htmlspecialchars($questions) . '</h4>' . "\n";

                    //Get answers
                    $domTable = $dom->getElementsByTagName("simpleChoice");

                    //Loop through each answer
                    foreach ($domTable as $answers)
                    {
                        //Delete potential unnecessary tags
                        $pattern = array(
                                            '<p xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1">', 
                                            '</p>'
                                    );

                        //Check if answer is correct one
                        if ($correct == $answers->getAttribute('identifier'))
                        {
                            //Print out correct answer
                            echo '<span style="color:red;">' . utf8_decode(str_replace($pattern, '', innerHTML($answers))) . '</span><br />' . "\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Print out answer
                            echo utf8_decode(str_replace($pattern, '', innerHTML($answers))) . '<br />' . "\n";
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        //Increment counter
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Goodness, that IS long code indeed. Any way you can clip the noise that isn't quite so relevnat and keep to the good stuff?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Much less code now.

Comment: is question are in sequential order in xml i.e. 1-10 in item101008.xml and then in 11-20 in item101009.xml also how the question sequence is in a single file random or in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using opendir/readdir, use scandir.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php.  scandir returns you a sorted array of files in the directory.  You should be able to drop this in and have your code work with minimal changes, other than replacing the outer while readdir loop with:

```
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $file) {
   //your current code
}
```